# Autodesk Construction Cloud - Retrieve project users

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-construction-cloud

How can I retrieve the users in a particular Autodesk Construction Cloud project?

In the past, I'd been using [this API call](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/admin-v1-projects-projectId-users-GET/). But somewhere along the line this stopped working for Autodesk Construction Cloud projects. It still works fine for me in BIM 360 projects.

I have tried:

Requested Resource:
`bim360/admin/v1/projects/d55af500-a5c5-44e6-9917-cf36ef71340a/users?limit=100`
Response Content:
`{\"pagination\":{\"limit\":100,\"offset\":0,\"totalResults\":0},\"results\":[]}`

If I go to the ACC webpage for this project (https://acc.autodesk.com/project-admin/members/projects/d55af500-a5c5-44e6-9917-cf36ef71340a) then the Project Members list looks like this:

[image: ACC Project Members]

So I'm confused why my GET request is returning 0 results when clearly I am a project member. My first thought was that the resource `bim360/admin/v1/projects/:projectId/users` no longer works on Autodesk Construction Cloud projects, but I couldn't find any ACC-specific alternatives in the [ACC Documentation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a known issue.  Those APIs are listed as incompatible here:

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/overview/bim-360-compatibility/compatibility-table/

But it was behaving as if it is working but stopped working recently. Ideally, those incompatible endpoints should have been blocked in the code, but it wasn’t.  Sorry for the confusion.

For Issues API, we now have ACC-specific endpoints. You will need to use the new one:

https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/acc-issues-api-general-availability

**FYI**:  ACC version does not support pushpin.  If you need pushpin support, let us know.  We will need to add your name to the wish.

For **Project Admin API**, you will need to wait for the new one. One positive news is that Project Admin API for ACC is currently under private beta. (project creation and project users).  We hope to move to public beta in a month or so. In a meantime, if you would like to join the private beta, are willing to test quickly, and give us feedback, you may contact your company’s Customer Success Manager (CMS) and request to sign up.

Once again sorry for the inconvenience this is causing.